# Transforming only y variable with Yeo-Johnson in Python

Tags: python, dependent-variable, transform

I have 4500 values in my dependent variable and 75% of values are zeros (no negative ones)

The distribution looks like this.

[image]

In multiple sources I read that Yeo-Johnson transformation can be a solution here.

I want to transform only y variable.

When I am doing a basic transformation with

```
y = df[['y']]
X = df.drop(columns=['y'])

from sklearn.preprocessing import PowerTransformer
pt = PowerTransformer(method='yeo-johnson')
y = pt.fit_transform(y)
```

Now my distribution looks like this one

[image]

with only two values.

```
array([[-0.3557652 ],
   [ 2.81469728],
   [-0.3557652 ],
   ...,
   [-0.3557652 ],
   [-0.3557652 ],
   [-0.3557652 ]])

print(pt.lambdas_)

[-3.78267763]
```

What am I doing wrong here? If I am doing it right, why is it like this? Should not it be close to normal? Any ideas how to proceed further?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve??  Clearly you cannot transform any such dataset to be even remotely Normal: 75% of its values must be tied.

Comment: Thanks, @whuber. I am trying to predict a score of each person, based on certain parameters. Yeah, probably an extreme example. What would you recommend?

Comment: You don't supply enough information, because this problem concerns the *relation* between two or more variables, not the distribution of a single variable.  The latter tells us almost nothing about the former.

Comment: @whuber, which information would be great to know for you to give some tips? I am trying to predict the score of experts based on their publications. My dependent variable is the impact factor of journals multiplied by articles. Independent variables include the number of article, the number of citations, etc.